# How to integrate this where $k$ takes values from 0 but $Γ(0)$ is coming infinite?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, graphing-functions

I have this equation which I am not able to integrate and plot:

$$F(y)=\int_{A_{3}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}\left[1+\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{y-\mu}{\sqrt{2}z}\right)\right]f(z)dz $$

where $f(z)$ is given by:
$$f(z)=L\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m-1}{k}(-A_3)^{m-1-k}z^k\exp(-bz).$$

Here, $L$, $b$, $A_3$, $μ$ are constants, $\mathrm{erf}(\cdot)$ is the error function and $m$ takes integer values.

Comment: Could you provide a context for this integral? Maybe there's another way to express this integral.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco  I have conditional Gaussian CDF $F(y|z)$  where $z$ being variance is also Random variable. To find unconditional CDF, I have to follow this approach. Where $f(z)$ is PDF of variance .

Comment: Not sure why to compute $F_Y(y)$ directly. You could try $f_Y(y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{Y \mid Z}(y \mid z) f(z) \,\mathrm{d} z$ first.

Comment: $f_Y(y)$ is not convergent in range $A3$ to $\infty$